# I implemented an ItemLoader in my scrapy project to format that data and it is no longer adding anything to the csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I create a scrapy project to scrape a few information off this classifieds website, however the data I was getting needed to be formatted. After doing some research I figured out how to implement an ItemLoader but now it does not write any scraped data to the csv file.

Here's my spider.py:

```
import scrapy
from..items import TestItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class TestSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    page_number = 2
    start_urls = ['https://jamaicaclassifiedonline.com/auto/cars/']

    def parse(self, response):

        for car in response.css('.col.l3.s12.m6'):
            items = TestItem()

            product_title = car.css('.jco-card-title::text').extract()
            product_imagelink = car.css('.card-image img::attr(data-src)').getall()
            urls = car.css('.card-image a::attr(href)').getall()

            for url in urls:
                url = response.urljoin(url)
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

            if product_title and product_imagelink:
                items['urls'] = urls

    def parse_details(self, response):
        l= ItemLoader(item=TestItem(), selector=response)
        l.add_css('product_title','#title::text')

        yield l.load_item()

        pass
```

Here's my items.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, TakeFirst
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

class TestItem(scrapy.Item):
    product_title = scrapy.Field(input_processors= MapCompose(remove_tags),output_processor= TakeFirst())

    pass
```

Here's my setting.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'test'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['test.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'test.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
```

}

Here's my pipeline.py:

```
class TestPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

Comment: Does your callback get called? What’s the output of `load_item()`?

Comment: It outputs example: `{'product_title': '\nFor Sale: HONDA FIT / JAZZ RS 2017 New Import '}` @Gallaecio

Comment: command I use is `scrapy crawl test -t csv -o testfile.csv`

Comment: Does your `parse_details` callback get called?

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* pipelines enabled to use ItemLoader, try without.

Comment: I tried without the pipeline and it still didn't work.